How to speed up training of Random Forest Regression and SVR?
I am  trying to create a regression model to predict the closing price of bitcoin using the folloςing dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/prasoonkottarathil/btcinusd/data?select=BTC-2021min.csv
It has over 600k records with 15 features (some that I created).
I have tried to train it on google colab and on my laptop multiple times. I even left it overnight but it is taking way too long.
Is there some way to speed it up?
Laptop Specs:
CPU: Ryzen 7 5800H  
GPU: RTX 3050  
RAM: 16 gb

This is the training code:
models = {
    'Linear Regression': {
        'model': LinearRegression(),
        'params': {}
    },
    'Ridge Regression': {
        'model': Ridge(random_state=42),
        'params': {'alpha': [0.01, 0.1, 1, 5, 10, 50, 100]}
    },
    'Lasso Regression': {
        'model': Lasso(random_state=42),
        'params': {'alpha': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10]}
    },
    'Decision Tree': {
        'model': DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=42),
        'params': {'max_depth': [None, 5, 10, 20], 'min_samples_split': [2, 5, 10]}
    },
    'Random Forest': {
        'model': RandomForestRegressor(random_state=42),
        'params': {'n_estimators': [50, 100, 200], 'max_depth': [None, 5, 10], 'min_samples_split': [2, 5, 10]}
    },
    'Support Vector Regression': {
        'model': SVR(),
        'params': {'kernel': ['linear', 'rbf'], 'C': [0.1, 1, 10], 'epsilon': [0.01, 0.1, 1]}
    }
}

results = {}

for model_name, model_data in models.items():
    print(f"Tuning {model_name}")
    grid_search = GridSearchCV(model_data['model'], model_data['params'], cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', verbose=1)
    grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)

    # Get the best model
    best_model = grid_search.best_estimator_

    # Predictions
    y_pred = best_model.predict(X_test)

    # Performance Metrics
    mae = mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred)
    mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
    rmse = np.sqrt(mse)
    r2 = r2_score(y_test, y_pred)

    results[model_name] = {
        'MAE': mae,
        'MSE': mse,
        'RMSE': rmse,
        'R2': r2,
        'Best Model': best_model,
        'Best Params': grid_search.best_params_
    }


This might not speed up the training time significantly but you can try to optimize your data, for example use float32 instead of float64. You can also use early stopping for random forest since it doesn’t natively use GPU. You can also profile the code and see the bottlenecks that's making the training slow.
